# regex match string agasint a pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string, pattern-matching, match

I'm new to regular expression.

What I want to archieve is to check if a string text match the following pattern.

```
"xxx(name="yyy", country="yyy")"
```

**Edited:**
xxx can be letters or numbers of any length, but must start with a letter. yyy can be any characters of any length. There can be zero or any number of white spaces between "," and "country".

For example, the following is a valid string

```
"TargetVal(name="White House", country="US")"
```

the following strings are not valid

```
"TargetVal(name="White House", country="US")+546+!!!"
"343TargetVal(name="White House", country="US")"
"!TargetVal(name="White House", country="US")"
"CenterVal(name="Green House",789808 country="US")"
"CenterVal(name="Green House", country="US", dfjl)"
"OuterVal(name=Green House, country="US")"
```

Here is what I have done so far in C#

```
var formula = @"TargetVal(name=""White House"", country=""US"")";
var pattern = @"\w\(name=""\w"",\sccy=""\w""\)";
ismatching= Regex.IsMatch(formula, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Obviously it's not working against all the specified rules. Can someone give some hint?

Comment: regex character classes like `\s` and `\w` match exactly one character, unless you add modifiers.  So in your example you are looking for exactly one word character, exactly one space, and so on.  Use modifiers like `*` (match 0 or more) and `+` (match one or more).

Comment: One way to build a regex, particularly if you are just getting started, is to start with your exact matching string.  Make sure it matches succesfully.  Then start replacing constant values with regex terms.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very helpful suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?i)^[a-z][a-z0-9]+\(name="".*?"",\s*country="".*?""\)$");
```

See <kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/FR2saf)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try `var pattern = "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\\(name=\"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\",\\s*country=\"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\"\\)$";`

I made the assumption, that your `xxx` does not only exist out of letters and numbers, but may include spaces (as `White House` does include them).